# Load a dictionary into django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have a csv file that has multiple headers.  I would like to get the data into a database using Django.  The first token of each line indicates which type of event it is and identifying the table it needs to go in.  I go through each line, matching up the headers and using a switch I’m ready to pass a correct dictionary to the model.  I can’t finger out how to pass the dictionary into the model. I don’t want to go attribute by attribute because all the tables would be almost 10k lines of code.  Is there a way to say

```
Event_{type}.objects.create(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Python's list unpacking argument:

```
Event_{type}.objects.create(**my_dict)
```

Make sure your dict keys are matching the db column names.

Comment: Thanks Marco.  I will have to double check my attribute names.  For future reference if I wanted to add a calculated variable could I do something like this? Event_{type}.objects.create(calculed_value=value, **my_dict)

Comment: Yes sure, this is possible.